# HighStock Navigator Handles are not moving

Tags: highcharts

I am using highstock by HighChart
When I provided certain data to HighStock, Handles of Navigators are unable to move.
its fiddle is http://jsfiddle.net/AbdulQ/ZvK7s/8/
Why its navigator handles are unable to move for specific data?

```
[1396310400000,40189.80078125],
[1398902400000,168386.40625],
[1401580800000,101377.5]
```

, but not for a large range of data? fiddle with large data is http://jsfiddle.net/AbdulQ/ZvK7s/9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out code

```
 xAxis: {
    range: 86400000 * 30*6, // 6 months
    minRange: 2,
    labels: {
        zIndex: 6,
    },
    tickInterval: 30*24*3600*1000, // 30 days
},
```

minRange: Number

The minimum range to display on this axis. The entire axis will not be allowed to span over a smaller interval than this. For example, for a datetime axis the main unit is milliseconds. If minRange is set to 3600000, you can't zoom in more than to one hour.

http://jsfiddle.net/patelrachith/ZvK7s/11/

Answer (score 2):

You should define [minRange](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.minRange) parameter, not range. Additionally, you have too much value.

Comment: Why not range? too much value? you mean too high value, right?

Comment: I mean that in our product, range paramenetr doenst exist, only minRange parameter.